# Change type of a component in Matisse

Tags: java, netbeans, types, matisse

Is there a way to change the type of a component when using Matisse in NetBeans?
I would like to switch a standard JDesktopPane to my own extended version. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include custom panel with NetBeans GUI Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816286/how-to-include-custom-panel-with-netbeans-gui-builder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all visual Components for Standalone Application(s) in Java are based on [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/),

Comment: Yep, but Matisse just blocks all editing of the code that it manages so I cannot directly change the type of that component. And I can't find any way to do that in the GUI as well..

Comment: @Valerio Santinelli I think that there must be lots of problems how to overrode JSR296 (Matisse) back to the Swing, but plain Swing isn't WYSIWYG editor,

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type outside of NetBeans using a text editor, change the `.form` and the `.java`. [Here](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic23821.html) is a similar question in the NetBeans forums with some answers.