# Canvas/JPanel not displaying on the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `MyFrame` class which extends `JFrame` . I added components(Controls i.e buttons) to this frame using the design options in NET BEANS. I have a `MyCanvas` class which extends `JPanel` with an overridden `paintComponent()` method . I am trying to add this component to `MyFrame` class. But when i add it and make it visible the canvas(`JPanel`) doesn't show itself on the `JFrame`. 
(First I was trying to add `Mycanvas` class extended by `Canvas`. But then i read a thread here to try and change it to `JPanel`. I didn't work either. And for canvas i obviously use paint not `paintcomponent()`)
My code is here below

**MyCanvas Class**

```
 public class MyCanvas extends javax.swing.JPanel{

 MyCanvas()
 {
      super();
 }

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D graphics2D=(Graphics2D)g;

    graphics2D.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10);

    graphics2D.drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);
}

}
```

**MyFrame**

```
public class Myframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Myframe() {

    initComponents();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  +generatedcode by the designer

 private void RectangleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
}

private void SquareActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
}

private void CircleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Myframe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
public void run() {
        new Myframe().setVisible(true);
    }
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton Circle;
private javax.swing.JButton Rectangle;
private javax.swing.JButton Square;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

**My Main Program**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyCanvas c = new MyCanvas();
    Myframe f= new Myframe();//Works if used JFrame instead of MyFrame

    f.add(c);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Basically i want to create a GUI in which i want Buttons which can trigger events and change what is drawn on a canvas. I tried it with an empty jframe. added the canvas/panel to the JFrame . It worked. Also I changed my Panel/Canvas and refresehed the frame. That also worked fine. But i am unable to do it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is that you are mixing creating `JFrame` with IDE and creating `JPanel` yourself, remember the IDE adds all components to `JFrame` in `initComponents()` which is ideally where you'd want to have your `Canvas` added.

either create the `JFrame` and `JPanel` by yourself (without use of Netbeans GUI Builder)

or

You can use the *Palette Manager* of Netbeans to add your `Component` to the palette, then you can use it in the GUI builder as you would any other class:

- [How can I use a custom subclass of a Swing component?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormUsingCustomComponent)

(Simply drag the `Canvas` class from the *projects tree* on to the `JFrame` in the GUI designer)

To make sure your custom `Canvas` functions:

- override `getPrefferedSize(..)` and return a size which fits

**Reference:**

- [How to include custom panel with NetBeans GUI Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816286/how-to-include-custom-panel-with-netbeans-gui-builder)

Comment: Okay so now i have edited according to you instructions and my canvas shows itself . But as the initcomponents method has been removed it does not show the buttons that i added. I want the buttons and the canvas should show itself .Was this the expected result .Any way to do it according to my requirements?

Comment: My buttons should be as I have placed them in the designer. The canvas should at least show itself along with the button.(I didnt go as far considering the position of the canvas). Where should i call the initComponents methods.?I should get some positive result that canvas and button both are being shown.If you can please guide me how i can set the canvas postion.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do . I will study thoroughly it and try to implement. Thankyou @David Kroukamp

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyCanvas c = new MyCanvas();
    Myframe f= new Myframe();//Works if used JFrame instead of MyFrame

    f.add(c);
    c.setVisible(true);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, the code in your `MyFrame` class:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Myframe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

won't be executed unless you are running `MyFrame` instead of your program main.

Also check that you have a `super()` call in your `MyFrame` constructor.

Comment: No doesn.t work .I have also tried many time

    `f.invalidate();`
     `f.validate();`
    ` f.repaint();`

Comment: How would I run the main code of MyFrame(as you are saying) ?
Added super() in MyFrame but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    Graphics2D graphics2D=(Graphics2D)g;

    graphics2D.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10);

    graphics2D.drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```